# librdkafka consumer and ssl configuration

Tags: c, ssl, apache-kafka, librdkafka, apache-kafka-security

I'm using librdkafka as a client consumer, and I have configured the broker and the client to support SSL, for the broker:

```
listeners = PLAINTEXT://172.20.54.9:9092,SSL://172.20.54.9:9093
ssl.keystore.location=E:/project_files/Project/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/config/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=ismail
ssl.key.password=ismail
ssl.truststore.location=E:/project_files/Project/kafka_2.11-2.1.0/config/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
```

in  the client side I'm using this configuration:

```
rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "metadata.broker.list", "172.20.54.9:9093",
                      NULL, 0);
rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "security.protocol", "ssl",
                      NULL, 0);
rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "ssl.ca.location", "/usr/bin/NetSens/CARoot.pem",
                      NULL, 0);
rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "ssl.certificate.location", "/usr/bin/NetSens/certificate.pem",
                      NULL, 0);
rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "ssl.key.location", "/usr/bin/NetSens/key.pem",
                      NULL, 0);
rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "ssl.key.password", "password",
                      NULL, 0);
```

And I'm receiving this error:

```
1559309856.897 RDKAFKA-3-ERROR: rdkafka#consumer-1: [thrd:ssl://172.20.54.9:9093/bootstrap]: ssl://172.20.54.9:9093/bootstrap: SSL handshake failed: ../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:  (after 7ms in state CONNECT)
```

For more information, I have in parallel another python kafka client using the same certificates and keys and it works fine.
I will be so grateful for any help.

Comment: Did you use `keytool` to generate the certificates?

Comment: Yes, I've used keytool to generate certificates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your problem is related to [this issue](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/1765).

You can fix it by including `-keyalg RSA` when invoking `keytool -genkey` to generate the certificates.